# How to delete specific data stored in realtime database in Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

**I have a problem with delete data from my Firebase Data. When I click on the delete button on one of the notes listed. It deletes all the databases stored in a real-time database. I just want to delete the selected data**

**This is NoteActivity.kt**

```
class NoteActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private var noteId = ""
    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    private var noteConnector: NoteConnector? = null
    private var noteList: MutableList<Note>? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note)

        val btn_back = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_back)

        btn_back.setOnClickListener({
            startActivity(Intent(this, MenuPage::class.java))
            finish()
        })


        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser


        var recyclerView: RecyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_note)
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        linearLayoutManager.reverseLayout = false
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        noteList = ArrayList()
        noteConnector = NoteConnector( this, noteList as ArrayList<Note>)
        recyclerView.adapter = noteConnector

        displayNote()

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            if (editText_note!!.text.toString() == "")
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@NoteActivity, "Please write something here.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else
            {
                addNote()
            }
        })

    }

     private fun addNote() {
        val noteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Note")
           
        val noteId = noteRef.push().key

        val noteMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        noteMap["noteID"] = noteId!!
        noteMap["noteDetail"] = editText_note!!.text.toString()
        noteMap["notePublisher"] = firebaseUser!!.uid

        noteRef.child(noteId).updateChildren(noteMap)

        Toast.makeText(this, "Task is added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

   
        editText_note!!.text.clear()
    }

    private fun displayNote()
    {
        val noteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            .child("Note")
            .child(noteId)

        noteRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (p0.exists())
                {
                    noteList!!.clear()

                    for (snapshot in p0.children)
                    {
                        val note = snapshot.getValue(Note::class.java)
                        noteList!!.add(note!!)
                    }

                    noteConnector!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }

}
```

**This is NoteConnector.kt**

```
class NoteConnector(
    private val mContext: Context,
    private val mNote: MutableList<Note>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteConnector.ViewHolder>() {

    private var firebaseUser:  FirebaseUser? = null
    private var noteId = ""

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteConnector.ViewHolder
    {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.note_page, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int
    {
        return mNote!!.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteConnector.ViewHolder, position: Int)
    {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        val note = mNote!![position]

        holder.viewNote.text = note.getNoteDetail()

        holder.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener {
            deleteNote()

            mNote.remove(note)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }

    private fun deleteNote() {

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Note")
            .child(noteId!!)
            .removeValue()


        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }


    //access note
    inner class ViewHolder (@NonNull itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {

        var viewNote : TextView
        var buttonDelete : ImageView

        init {
            viewNote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_on_note)
            buttonDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_task_delete)

        }
    }
```

[image: image database edited]

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `noteId` inside `.child(noteId!!)`?

Comment: the noteId is the id of the specific note added in the realtime database.

Comment: You saying about this line `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Note")
.child(noteId!!).removeValue()`?

Comment: yes. or maybe I did wrongly for the whole concept? because I am a new beginner. can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the removeValue() operation to see if something's wrong?

Comment: yes. It deletes all the data stored inside the realtime database. However, I just want to delete the selected data.

Comment: Are you sure that the `noteId` is the same as the id in the database? Does it start with `-M`?

Comment: I am not sure. So, I edit something like this by editing the addNote() function in NoteActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you define `noteId` as:

```
private var noteId = ""
```

And never give it a value. When you then call:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Note")
    .child(noteId!!)
    .removeValue()
```

It deletes `/Note/`, so it deletes all notes.

You will need to ensure that `noteId` is set to the key of the note you want to delete.

I'd typically do this by passing the key into your `deleteNote` function when you call it:

```
private fun deleteNote(String noteId) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Note")
        .child(noteId!!)
        .removeValue()

    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

And then you call it with something like this:

```
holder.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener {
    deleteNote(node.id) // this needs to be the key of the note that the user clicked on

    mNote.remove(note)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```